# Function argument pass-by-value faster than pass-by-reference?

Tags: c++, optimization, copy-elision

I had an interview, where I get the following function declaration:

```
int f1(const std::vector<int> vec)
```

I suggested that instead of copying the vector, we should use a const-reference(not to mention that const copy does not makes much sense), but the interviewer claimed that the compiler copy-elision will handle it. I couldn't come up with any strong argument at the spot, but today I did some research.

I implemented the following two simple example functions:

```
int f1(const std::vector<int> vec) {
    const auto num = vec.size();
    return num * num;
}


int f2(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    const auto num = vec.size();
    return num * num;
}
```

From the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/na5E3xGdY) assembly, it is clear that the `f2` function has 2 additional instructions so it should be slower. (I think 2 `mov` is technically almost free in modern CPUs)

I also used quick-bench to measure the two solutions, but it is confirmed my suspicion, that passing const-ref is faster. (even for 1 element)

[image]

I suspected that maybe copy-elision is not allowed because of `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);`, but after removing it, I received a similar result.

Now I have these results, but I think it is still not convincing enough.

**What do you think?**

**Do you have any good argument for using one over the other?**

Comment: unclear how copy-elision should come into play here.

Comment: It shouldn't matter once the functions are inlined. You should test them in real-world code that does something useful and compiler may change inlining behavior.

Comment: Without compiler optimisations viewing the assembly for performance analysis is fairly meaningless

Comment: Surprisingly for me, in this simple case gcc indeed optimizes out vector copying, but just because it is smart enough to understand that we only care about the size of the vector. In general case, where you actually need to do some complex operation using the vector passed as arg, I would rather avoid passing it by value.

Comment: 1. You should have told to your interviewer that very smart people  hadn't implemented std::string_view, and std::span if he/she was true. 

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the assembly of the functions `f1` and `f2` won't work. With optimizations enabled they are likely to look completely identical. (Except that in some ABIs it is the callee's responsibility to destroy function parameters, in which case `f1` will look much longer. But that doesn't mean anything by itself. There will be destruction of any created object somewhere anyway, whether in the caller or the callee.)

The performance difference here doesn't lie *inside* the function, but in the potential caller.

Function parameters are constructed in the context of the caller, not in the context of the callee. So, here if `f1` is called like

```
std::vector<int> vec{/*...*/};
auto res = f1(vec);
```

will cause `vec` to be copied into the function parameter in the caller. It is not possible to elide the copy. (Of course the compiler is free to optimize the copy away if it can see that doing so won't change the observable behavior of the program, but that generally can't happen if the function isn't inlined, for example because it's definition is in another translation unit and there is no link-time optimization.)

With

```
std::vector<int> vec{/*...*/};
auto res = f2(vec);
```

no copy is done, even conceptually. Copy elision is not relevant.

It is true that e.g.

```
std::vector<int> vec{/*...*/};
auto res = f1(std::move(vec));
```

will use the move constructor and will generally be cheap enough that it might be faster than using `f2` under some circumstances where the function can't be inlined. (However that will depend on how the ABI specifies that a `std::vector` is passed to functions as well.)

It is also true that e.g.

```
auto res = f1(std::vector<int>{/*...*/});
```

will construct only one `std::vector<int>` if copy elision is applied (guaranteed since C++17 and optionally before). However, the same is true if `f2` was used.

In some situations `f1` might be a better choice, because the compiler can be sure that it doesn't modify `vec` from the caller. (A `const` reference does not strictly mean that the referenced object can't be modified.) This may allow the compiler to make some optimizations in the caller without having to analyze the body of `f1` that it might not be able to do with `f2`.

So all in all I would say, in some circumstances they are equally good, in some circumstances `f2` is definitively the better choice and in some more rare situations it might be that `f1` is the better choice. I would go with `f2` by default.

However, looking at the bigger picture, I would try to avoid having a function which iterates over a vector take the vector itself as parameter. Functions like this can typically be written more generally to apply to arbitrary ranges and hence it would probably be easy to make them templates and use either the iterator interface or the C++20 range interface used by standard library algorithms. This way, if in the future someone decides to use some other container than `std::vector`, the function will still just work.

Comment: just as examples: In https://godbolt.org/z/n9d88nGGn you see that `f1()` will call `new` twice while in https://godbolt.org/z/KKTxev63r `f2()` will only call `new` once. And finally in https://godbolt.org/z/xP3jfY1nK you see `f1()` called with `std::move` and the compiler optimizing away one of the vectors. But that's because in constructor/destructor the `new` and `delete` cancel each other and the constructor/destructor calls are trvial. Note: It's the original vector that gets optimized away, the copy for `f1()` remains I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Just assuming copy-elision is not a good idea: copying a vector is very expensive involving memory management and potentially copying a lot. Risking this copy over some marginal gain that you could have is not a good bet unless you know the behavior of your current and future compilers (copy-elision may be done, but is not mandated). One way to check whether copy elision was actually done is to check the pointer to the vector data on the caller side and in the function. Even if speed is not the greatest concern, more programmers expect the pass-by-const-ref over pass-by-value and thus don't have to question the reason for the decision.

Mind you that copy-elision is mandatory for initialization (from the link: when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type)

See also on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)